# What is meant by "drive temperature" and "power-on hours" in SeaTools?

Tags: hard-drive

I use SeaTools for Windows to check my hard drive:

[image]

Is **drive temperature** the same as my laptop temperature?

Is **power-on hours** meaning how long my laptop had been running?

Also, the security status is 29 hours?

Is the 8mb cache size meaning the total cache size is 8mb? or is it 8mb per slot or smt (i'm clueless when it comes to hard-ware)

Comment: Couldn't you *guess* what the "drive temperature" specifies? Isn't it kind-of self explaining? What do you specifically want to know about the temperature? Same for "power-on hours".

Comment: You may find the user guide helpful: http://www.seagate.com/support/seatools/SeaTools_for_Windows.pdf

Comment: Security status is a number in hexadecimal format (ie: 29h = 29(h)exadecimal = 29 in base 16) and not a value in hours: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexadecimal

Comment: @slhck i could guess but i could guess wrongly too. why not Ask to be Sure?

Comment: Yes, but next time tell us what *you* think it is so you will get a more specific answer :) @pac

Comment: WTH -6 votes? lol man, is this even a bad question?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"Drive Temperature" is telling you the current temperature of the drive, in both Celsius and Fahrenheit. (57C/135F).

"Power-On Hours" Is how many hours (total) the drive has been powered-on.

The "8MB cache size", means the drive has 8 megabytes of cache/buffer; [see here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cache#Disk_cache) for more info on what a drive cache is.

I'm not sure what the the "Security Status" actually represents (perhaps signifies that there is a HDD-level password enabled, or not, etc.), but the "29h" means "29 in hexidecimal", and not "29 hours".

Comment: does the temp of the drive is the same as the temp of the laptop? or rather the motherboard or smt?

Comment: Is the 8mb cache size meaning the total cache size is 8mb? or is it 8mb per slot or smt (i'm clueless when it comes to hard-ware)

Comment: @Pacerier - The drive's temperature will be independent from the motherboard temperature (aside form how one's heat may affect the other).  Many MB's even have multiple thermal detection points.  As for your cache question, go read the wikipedia article in my answer and come back and ask new (specific) question(s).

Comment: do you mean the 3 paragraphs under **disk cache** heading, because i've definitely done that before asking that question..